# Помогите пожалуйста решить задачу по Python! Мой код не гибкий(((

Tags: python

У меня получается решить, только для конкретного примера, но если немного поменять условие примера, то код не работает. А именно если добавить еще 1-2 столба, то вылазят ошибки.

Задача:
Люди стоят в ряд. Между ними есть столбы, которые не могут быть перемещены. Как переставить людей по их высоте в возрастающем порядке, не перемещая столбы. Столбы это -1

Например: Для a = [-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180] вывод должен быть sortByHeight(a) = [-1, 150, 160, 170, -1, -1, 180, 190].

```
a = [-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180]
for i in range(len(a)-1):
    for j in range(len(a)-i-1):
        if a[j]==-1:
            continue
        elif a[j]>a[j+1] and a[j+1]!=-1:
            a[j],a[j+1]=a[j+1],a[j]
        elif a[j]>a[j+2] and a[j+2]!=-1:
            a[j],a[j+2]=a[j+2],a[j]
        elif a[j]>a[j+3] and a[j+3]!=-1:
            a[j],a[j+3]=a[j+3],a[j]

print(a)
```

к примеру если в список a = [-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180] добавить еще 1 столбец -1, то получается a = [-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, -1, 160, 180]. С таким списком код уже перестает работать, так как a[j+3] максимум +3. Код не гибкий и не работает с любыми входными данными, а точнее с любым количеством -1

```
      IndexError Traceback (most recent call last)
      <ipython-input-2-2ce3d40d358a> in <module>
      6         elif a[j]>a[j+1] and a[j+1]!=-1:
      7             a[j],a[j+1]=a[j+1],a[j]
      8         elif a[j]>a[j+2] and a[j+2]!=-1:
      9             a[j],a[j+2]=a[j+2],a[j]
      10         elif a[j]>a[j+3] and a[j+3]!=-1:

      выдает ошибку: IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Приведенный код не выдает никакие ошибок. Добавьте в вопрос именно тот код, на котором возникают ошибки, и текст самих ошибок.

Comment: @insolor
к примеру если в список a = [-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180] добавить еще 2 столба -1, то получается a = [-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, -1, -1, 160, 180].  С таким списком код уже перестает работать, так как a[j+3] максимум +3. Код не гибкий и не работает с любыми входными данными, а точнее с любым количеством -1

Comment: Добавьте в сам вопрос. Под вопросом есть ссылка "править", чтобы его отредактировать. Вообще не особо интересны "столбы", нужен код, на котором воспроизводится ошибка, и текст ошибки.

Comment: @insolor
 стрелка ошибки указывает на 8 строчку кода - индекс списка вне допустимого диапазона, наверное надо цикл как то запустить, чтобы сортировка была с пропуском значений -1, но опыта нету, чтобы такой цикл написать)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = [-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, -1, -1, 160, 180]
b = [i for i in a if i > 0]
b.sort()
a = [ b.pop(0) if a[i] != -1 else -1 for i in range(len(a)) ]
print(a)
```

[-1, 150, 160, 170, -1, -1, -1, -1, 180, 190]

Comment: Спасибо большое, код отлично заработал. То, что нужно!